# Expecting the resolved value of a mock inside of a function under test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, promise, jestjs

Keep in mind, I'm fairly new to Jest, and I'm not deeply familiar with the internals of Node's `Promise`. I get that `async` functions are really functions that return a `Promise`, and I've had good success with that thinking.

I have a function that I'm trying to test. It has a dependency that it imports before doing any other work. Depending on the input passed to `foo`, that dependency may return different things which may or may not affect the result of `foo`. It goes something like:

```js
// foo.js

const someOtherWork = require("../bar/baz");

module.exports = async function foo() {
  const array = await someOtherWork();
  ... do other things ...
  return someStuff;
}
```

I import a function to help with the work that `foo` is trying to do.

In my tests, I spy on the `someOtherWork` function like so:

```js
// foo.test.js

const someOtherWork = jest.requireActual("../bar/baz");
const mockSomeOtherWork = jest.fn().mockImplementation(someOtherWork);
jest.mock("../bar/baz", () => mockSomeOtherWork);

const foo = require("./foo.js");

// ...tests...
```

With this, I'm able to assert that `mockSomeOtherWork` was called with specific parameters, and even that it returned the right output. Where I'm tripped up is when my mocked dependency (`someOtherWork` in this case) returns a `Promise`.

When I try to assert that the `Promise` resolved with a specific value *without calling the mock function in my test code*, it *always* passes the test:

```
expect(mockSomeOtherWork).toHaveReturnedWith(Promise.resolve([my, array, of, expected, values])); // succeeds correctly
expect(mockSomeOtherWork).toHaveReturnedWith(Promise.reject("lol nope"); // succeeds ERRONEOUSLY
```

I've successfully failed tests when I assert that it returns an `Array`, or anything else, like so:

```
expect(mockSomeOtherWork).toHaveReturnedWith(Array); // fails correctly
expect(mockSomeOtherWork).toHaveReturnedWith([my, array, of, expected, values]); // fails correctly
```

But any sort of `Promise` *passes* the test, which means I can assume nothing from my assertions!

I'm starting to figure out that, to Jest, a `Promise` is a mostly opaque object, and I must `await` it or attach callbacks (via `then` or `catch`) to figure out what's inside. Do promises not remember their already-resolved value for me to inspect later, without re-calling the function that returned it? I don't want to have to rely on asserting other dependencies of `someOtherWork`, or the return value of `foo`, as those options assume a lot about `foo` that might change at any time. I already have an effective spy-mock-thing in there on `someOtherWork`. Should I instead grab the returned `Promise` from `mockSomeOtherWork.mock.results[0].value` and `await` that? Is there a "correct" way to go about asserting the `async` result of a dependency of a unit under test?

Answer (score 9):

Here's my workaround:

```js
// If all is well, this should be a Promise
const results = mockSomeOtherWork.mock.results[0].value;

// If that Promise resolves to the right stuff, gucci!
const expected = [my, array, of, expected, values];
await expect(results).resolves.toStrictEqual(expected); // passes correctly

// This should fail, because the promise resolved to `expected`
const notExpected = [something, else];
await expect(results).resolves.toStrictEqual(notExpected); // fails correctly
```

I figure that, assuming `Promise` is opaque, I do need to `await` it to assert its value. I trust that no extra invocations or work will happen by me doing so, and I can prove this by asserting `expect(mockSomeOtherWork).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`. Since this assertion succeeds in the test both before and after my workaround above, that one call must be in the body of `foo`.

It would be nice if Jest had a set of `toHaveResolvedWith` matchers, but this works well enough for my purposes today.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Jest docs didn't have any info about this :/